# How can I change numbering in all of the file names?

Tags: unix, filenames

I have 1000 files, which have a format of framexxx.dat, such as

frame0.dat frame1.dat frame2.dat .... frame999.dat

I hope to change these file's name to

frame000.dat frame001.dat frame002.dat .... frame999.dat

Is there anyway to do this with simple linux command?

Also, if my files are framexx.dat or framexxxx.dat (xx are 2digit numbers and xxxx are 4 digit numbers) then how can I change the code to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to handle them by groups:

- group 0: from `frame100.dat` to `frame999.dat`: nothing to do here.
- group 1: from `frame10.dat` to `frame99.dat`: add one 0

  ```
  for i in {10..99}; do mv frame$f.dat frame0$f.dat; done
  ```
- group 2: from `frame0.dat` to `frame9.dat`: add 2 0s

  ```
  for i in {0..9}; do mv frame$f.dat frame00$f.dat; done
  ```

A general guideline is to handle the big numbers first (in some cases some complications could arise)

This can be extended to bigger numbers...you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you~! This worked nicely~! It was so simpler than I expected.